# How to replace text with an image in JQuery table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting JSON values and display them in a JQuery table. There are values called "Success", "Failed" and "Aborted". I want to show them with image icons of Success.png, Failed.png and Aborted.png. Can you please help me how to do so. Thanks in advance.

Following are the Json and JQuery table I used so far:

```
$.post( "/portal/controllers/apis/test.jag",{
    action: "getData"
}, function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("----------------------------------start----------------------------");
       $("#tableid").append("<tr><td> Product </td> <td > Day01 </td> <td> Day02 </td> <td> Day03 </td><td> Day07 </td><td> Components </td> </tr>");


        for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            $("#tableid").append("<tr><td>" + result[i].product + "</td><td>" + result[i].Day01 +
            "</td><td>" + result[i].Day02 + "</td><td>" + result[i].Day03 +
            "</td><td>" + result[i].Day07 + "</td><td>" + result[i].Component + "</td></tr>");

    }
});
```

Json data

```
   {
      "Product":"APIM",
      "Day01":"Success",
      "Day02":"Aborted",
      "Day03":"Failed",
      "Day04":"Failed",
      "Day05":"Failed",
      "Day06":"Failed",
      "Day07":"Success"
   },
   {
      "Product":"AppFactory",
      "Day01":"Aborted",
      "Day02":"Success",
      "Day03":"Success",
      "Day04":"Success",
      "Day05":"Success",
      "Day06":"Success",
      "Day07":"Success"
   },
```

Comment: May be you can use if else if else statement if(day1=="success"){<img>... Something like this or switch statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My title</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var result = [{
        "Product": "APIM",
        "Day01": "Success",
        "Day02": "Aborted",
        "Day03": "Failed",
        "Day04": "Failed",
        "Day05": "Failed",
        "Day06": "Failed",
        "Day07": "Success"
    },
    {
        "Product": "AppFactory",
        "Day01": "Aborted",
        "Day02": "Success",
        "Day03": "Success",
        "Day04": "Success",
        "Day05": "Success",
        "Day06": "Success",
        "Day07": "Success"
    }];
    window.onload = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            $("#tableid").append("<tr><td>" + result[i].Product + "</td><td><img src='" + result[i].Day01 + ".png' />" +
            "</td><td><img src='" + result[i].Day02 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='" + result[i].Day03 + ".png' />" +
            "</td><td><img src='" + result[i].Day07 + ".png' /></td><td><img src='" + result[i].Component + ".png' /></td></tr>");
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="tableid"></table>
</body>
</html>
```